# c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-stdlib=libc++' while installing a node package

Tags: npm, g++

Running npm install for a library fails with error:

> c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-stdlib=libc++'

Answer (score 23):

Running `npm install` with the enviroment variable `CXX=clang++` made it work:

```
CXX=clang++ npm install ...
```

Comment: Do you know why this is?

Comment: By default gyp will use the c++ executable. Unfortunately node-gyp does not "autoconfigure" your compiler settings. It will assume you are using clang and assume that the option --stdlib=libc++ is a valid option. Which in some cases, for example when you have g++ set as your main compiler (c++ points to g++) is not true.

Comment: do we have to do this everytime ?

Comment: why do node-gyp developers assume we always use clang on macOS?

Comment: what do you do if you need to install this in an environment where if must gave g++ as the compiler and cannot install clang?

Answer (score 5):

For those who are still having this problem, the below command worked for me on fish shell and macOS.

```
env CC=clang CXX=clang++ npm install XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW my issue was that I had a Conda installation without an active environment set.  E.g., `conda info` showed `None` as the active environment.

Not certain how that occurred (perhaps on Catalina install?), but once I set an environment (`source activate ___`) my npm installs started working again.

I had tried some of the other solutions (prefixing environment variables; upgrading Xcode tools, etc.), but this is what worked for me.